# Date picker & combo box values are not going to mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, datepicker

I am making a registration form in PHP and when submitting the form Date(Check In, for which I have used Date Picker), Combo boxes(Sex & Room No) & check box(taxi) is not getting inserted.

I have looked enough in to the code but not getting what is wrong..though other combo box and check box working just fine.

PHP Code -

```
<?php

$passport = $_POST['passport'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$sex = $_POST['sex'];
$address1 = $_POST['address1'];
$address2 = $_POST['address2'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$roomNo = $_POST['roomNo'];
if(isset($_POST['food']) && $_POST['food'] == 'food')
{
    $food = 'yes';
}
else
{
    $food = 'no';
}   
if(isset($_POST['car']) && $_POST['car'] == 'car')
{
    $car = 'yes';
}
else
{
    $car = 'no';
}
if(isset($_POST['others']) && $_POST['others'] == 'others')
{
    $others = 'yes';
}
else
{
    $others = 'no';
}
$checkIn = $_POST['checkIn'];


mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("guesthouse");

$personal_query = "INSERT INTO personal_details VALUES(
                                                        '',
                                                        '$name',
                                                        '$sex',
                                                        '$address1',
                                                        '$address2',
                                                        '$city',
                                                        '$country',
                                                        '$contact',
                                                        '$email')";
mysql_query($personal_query);
$result = mysql_affected_rows();

if($result == 1)
{
    echo "Personal Details Submitted";
}

$booking_query = "INSERT INTO booking VALUES(
                                                '',
                                                '$name',
                                                '$roomno',
                                                '$food',
                                                '$taxi',
                                                '$others',
                                                '$checkIn')";

mysql_query($booking_query);
$result = mysql_affected_rows();

if($result == 1) {
    echo "<br/>Booking Details Submitted";
}    
?>
```

HTML -

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="jsDatePick_ltr.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsDatePick.min.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        new JsDatePick({
            useMode:2,
            target:"checkIn",
            dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
            /*selectedDate:{                
                day:5,                  
                month:9,
                year:2006
            },
            yearsRange:[1978,2020],
            limitToToday:false,
            cellColorScheme:"beige",
            dateFormat:"%m-%d-%Y",
            imgPath:"img/",
            weekStartDay:1*/
        });
    };
</script>
</head>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="registration_handle.php">
  <table width="60%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#0099FF">Room Reservation Details :</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="33%" align="center" bgcolor="#66FFCC">Passport No </td>
      <td width="67%"><label for="textfield"></label>
      <input type="text" name="passport" id="passport"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#66FFCC">Name</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#66FFCC">Sex</td>
      <td><label for="select3"></label>
        <select name="sex" id="sex">
        <option value="" selected>Male</option>
        <option value="" >Female</option>
      </select></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#66FFCC">Address 1</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="address1" id="address1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#66FFCC">Address2</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="address2" id="address2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#66FFCC">City</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="city" id="city" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#66FFCC">Country</td>
      <td><label for="select2"></label>
        <select name="country" id="country">
        <?php
            mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
            mysql_select_db("guesthouse");

            $query = "SELECT name FROM country";
            $query_result = mysql_query($query);
            while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result))
            {
            ?>
                <option value = "<?php echo $result['name'] ?>"><?php echo $result['name'] ?></option>
            <?php
            }       
        ?>
      </select></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#66FFCC">Contact No</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="contact" id="contact"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#66FFCC">E-Mail </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#66FFCC">Room No</td>
      <td><label for="select4"></label>
        <select name="roomNo" id="roomNo">
        <?php
            mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
            mysql_select_db("guesthouse");

            $query = "SELECT name FROM roomno";
            $query_result = mysql_query($query);
            while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result))
            {
            ?>
                <option value = "<?php echo $result['name'] ?>"><?php echo $result['name'] ?></option>
            <?php
            }       
        ?>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#66FFCC">Extra Service</td>
      <td><p>
        <label>        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="food" value="food" />Food  
        <input type="checkbox" name="car" value="car" />Car 
        <input type="checkbox" name="others" value="others" />Others<br>
      </p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#66FFCC">Check In </td>
      <td><label for="textfield3"></label>
      <input type="text" size="16" name="checkIn" id="checkIn"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
      <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="Reset" value="Reset" />
      <input type="submit" name="cancel" id="cancel" value="Cancel" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

</html>
```

Comment: you need to specify your insert fields/rows go check INSERT : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html

Comment: When we send every value for any table we don't need to describe the fields name of the table.
Others fields values are getting inserted but only some given fields values are NULL

Comment: It could be nothing, but why don't you change the <label> tag so it matches the combo boxes (select)

Comment: which combo box you are talking about ?

Comment: he is telling you that your label are on select1-4 and your selects are not called like that at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

value of `sex` is `""` (if you want default, don't type value="") 
-Tested-

```
<html>
<body>

<select onchange="alert(this.value);">
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option value=''>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

you never give any value to `$taxi` (wich is called `car` in your form)

You initialte `$roomNo` and store `$roomno`

--- found these errors because I tend to do same things. here's a tip, always verify your variables name first, 99% of your probs will be fixed --- (works for me :) )

Comment: Yes these problem has been removed.

Can you please help me with inserting Date values too as I know I will have to change the format but don't know how to do..

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: personally i work with timestamp - they are easy to work with and compatible with almost everything. else you may want to check mysql date format.